# 0-1 Law: Applications?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

The question is more open to a debate rather than a mathematical explanation:

If $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras.
$\mathfrak{A}_n := \sigma(\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m)$ is the generated $\sigma$-algebra of the events $A_n, A_{n+1},...$ and $\mathfrak{A}_{\infty}:=\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \mathfrak{A}_n$ is the tail $\sigma$-Algebra. Then for any event $A \in \mathfrak{A}_{\infty}$ the probability that it will occur is either 1 or 0.

Where is the applicable part? The only examples I have been able to find are those concerning coins and "the infinite monkey" theorem, none of which seem rather applicable to a real life event. Is there any place (perhaps in physics or biology) where this will have an applicable meaning? Mathematically it's a beauty, I have no doubts about that.

Answer (score 0):

Using this law and the CLT you can show the following:

Let $(X_n)_n$ a sequence of iid random variables of finite variance. Then, $$ \limsup_n \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$$ a.s.

To show this, you fix a $c>0$ and use CLT to show that the event $\{limsup_n \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{\sqrt{n}} > c\}$ has positive probability. Note this event is a caudal event, so, by 0-1 law, it has probability one.

It is a general result for random walks with independents increments. What this result is telling is that your random walk stay a infinite number of times above the curve $a\sqrt{x}$ for all $a>0$. This gives you the typical behaviour of the trajectories.

Comment: There is also an application to the future behavior of the stock market.

Comment: I can imagine that the behavior of the stock market could be see as a random walk, but I saw once that the CLT it isn't a good tool to predict the future of stock market.

And to be honest I know nothing about stock market. I would like to know more, could you explain the application you have in mind?